# UIPageViewController & SDWebImage - Show error image when remote image's not available

Tags: objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, sdwebimage

I'm using a UIPageViewController in combination with SDWebImage to show an image gallery without zoom.

I fetch my images from remote, and sometimes happens that some images are not downloaded because of wrong URL, for example.

I would like to show an error image whenever the remote image's not being downloaded.

Does anyone know or suggest how could I do this? I've tried to look around Google but with no success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The bounty was put before the accepted answer. I forgot to give it, tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your own `errorImage` in a custom `SDWebImageCompletionBlock`:

```
[imageView
 sd_setImageWithURL:url
 placeholderImage:placeholderImage
 options:options
 progress:NULL
 completed:^(UIImage * image,
             NSError * error,
             SDImageCacheType cacheType,
             NSURL * imageURL)
 {
     if (error)
     {
         imageView.image = errorImage;
     }
 }];
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks a lot man! You'll get the bounty as soon as I can give it